# Using Map Tips and Ruled Expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression, css, maptips

QGIS 2.18.5

I'm trying to add a condition to my expression in my html/css map tips where if a value is *'null'*, the result will show *'no data available'*.

I've got a screenshot of my map tip so far for a feature with populated values (the date and the number of years). Not all the features have a date and integer associated with them.

[image]
[image]

What do I add to the code below?

`<h1> [%"Local Auth"%] </h1>
<h3> Date LAP Adopted</h3> <p> [% "Local Pl_1" %] </p>
<h3> Five Year Housing Supply</h3> <p> [% "5 YHLS (#)" %] </p>`

I tried

`<h3> Date LAP Adopted</h3> <p> [%CASE WHEN  "Local Pl_1" = ' ' THEN 'No Data Available' END%] </p>`

but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `coalesce()`

```
<h1> [%"Local Auth"%] </h1>
<h3> Date LAP Adopted</h3> <p> [% coalesce("Local Pl_1", 'No Data Available') %] </p>
<h3> Five Year Housing Supply</h3> <p> [% "5 YHLS (#)" %] </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your data it truly Null (and not a white space), then use IS NULL to detect it.

```
[%CASE WHEN  "Local Pl_1" IS NULL THEN 'No Data Available'
end%]
```

If the content of the field `Local Pl_1` is to be displayed if it set (i.e. it is not null for some records), you can instruct QGIS to show it:

```
[%CASE WHEN  "Local Pl_1" IS NULL THEN 'No Data Available' ELSE  "Local Pl_1" 
end%]
```

--> if record 1 has a null `"Local Pl_1"` value, then `No Data Available` is displayed. If record 2 has the value `"Local Pl_1" = Test`, then `Test` is displayed in the maptip.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean "Then if the data is not null, you can display it"? I didn't realise no entry was not the same and Null. Perhaps I need it coded for blank space instead

Comment: I clarified the post for the not-null case. Your example use a blank space (and you said doesn't work). If the solution using **is null** doesn't work either, you would have to check how "no data" is represented in your system (Null, empty string, white space etc).